# how can i open a btm file in visual studio 2010

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, biztalk

I need open a btm file in visual studio 2010.  I've already install biztalk 2009 (do I need other version?) but there's a visual studio icon of text file instead Biztalk icon file. The project is c#.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

BizTalk 2010 is the correct version for Visual Studio 2010.

Make sure you install Visual Studio 2010 prior to BizTalk 2010 and that you select *"Developer Tools and SDK"* during installation.

[image]

The .BTM file is normally part of a BizTalk project (.BTPROJ). If you do not have the actual project you could create one yourself and use the "Add existing item" VS feature.

[image]

Remember that the .BTM file only contains the links between schema-nodes and not the actual schemas which are needed to open and display the transformation properly in Visual Studio.

If you already have the BizTalk project file and the corresponding schemas you are ready to go. Otherwise you can find out what schemas it needs by looking at the SrcTree and TrgTree nodes in the top of the file. Note that if the referenced schema is found in another project/assembly the type-name rather than the schema-file-name will be shown here.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure you can open .btm files with Visual Studio.

To open your file, just open it with BizTalkMapper or BizTalkServer, depending on your needs.
Right click on your icon, click Properties, and chose BizTalk Software in Modify button, near to "Open With"

Your btm files will now open with the desired software

Comment: I don't know too much about Biztalk projects. where are those things(BizTalkMapper, BizTalkServer,) installed? Thanks for the answer

Comment: @Mirlo I'm not really familiar with BizTalk too. You can take a look at [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_BizTalk_Server) to have an overview. Do you success to open your file ?